# How to run java class in back ground of server in Maven / Vaadin project?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, vaadin, timertask

Problem: 
I need to run one java function every 24 h. It get some data from one site and it push that data to database. No i wonder how to create timer which will run successfully on Tom Cat server. I have maven/Vaadin project. So now i wonder how to start Timer function that will run on server not on site.

Whit quartz:

[image: arhucture]

timer:

```
public class TimerData implements org.quartz.Job {


    SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();


    public TimerData() throws SchedulerException, InterruptedException {
        sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        sched.start();
        Thread.sleep(90L * 1000L);
        sched.shutdown(true);
    }
    // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
    JobDetail job = newJob(TimerData.class)
            .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
            .build();
    // compute a time that is on the next round minute
    Date runTime = evenMinuteDate(new Date());

    // Trigger the job to run on the next round minute
    Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .startAt(runTime)
            .build();

    // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger


    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        // Say Hello to the World and display the date/time
        System.out.println("Hello World! - " + new Date());

        try {
            FillData.povni();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Contlistener:

```
public class ContListener implements ServletContextListener,
        HttpSessionListener, HttpSessionAttributeListener {
    private ServletContext context = null;
    // Public constructor is required by servlet spec
    public ContListener() {
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // ServletContextListener implementation
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
      /* This method is called when the servlet context is
         initialized(when the Web application is deployed). 
         You can initialize servlet context related data here.
      */
        context = sce.getServletContext();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
      /* This method is invoked when the Servlet Context 
         (the Web application) is undeployed or 
         Application Server shuts down.
      */
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // HttpSessionListener implementation
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
      /* Session is created. */
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
      /* Session is destroyed. */
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // HttpSessionAttributeListener implementation
    // -------------------------------------------------------

    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent sbe) {
      /* This method is called when an attribute 
         is added to a session.
      */
    }

    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent sbe) {
      /* This method is called when an attribute
         is removed from a session.
      */
    }

    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent sbe) {
      /* This method is invoked when an attibute
         is replaced in a session.
      */
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
        <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>quartz:start-on-load</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>ContListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You can write some cron jobs for that, basically your code will run on server. I am not sure what you meant by`not on site`. You can try http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: Setup up a cron job using `crontab -e` if your tomcat is running on linux

Comment: i assume you need something combined `cronjob` + `push`? (not sure about the last one)

Comment: I don't know if 'crontab or cronjob' can access my class in maven project, i have aws server so i have Linux there. But now I am trying to implement quartz-scheduler.org into my project.  Because it seams more programmatically.

Comment: @DhruvPal do you have any clue how to start 'quartz-scheduler' in maven/vaadin project?

Comment: have a look https://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/ @LenartPoljanšek

Comment: You can have maven dependency from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.1

Comment: @DhruvPal I did everything :( still not working

Comment: @LenartPoljanšek Please share your code

Comment: @DhruvPal I share it. If you need anything more just say :D  thank you a lot for help.

Comment: Personally I'd use spring to schedule a task

Comment: @ChrisM can you explain a litle more :D

Comment: Check out the spring documentation https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ You might decide it's a bit much to use spring just for that, but I use spring anyway. The Vaadin Spring integration is quite good too.

Comment: Okay I will create a dummy working project with quartz for you in 2 - 3 days @LenartPoljanšek

Comment: tnx :D @DhruvPal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Quartz is, indeed, one of the most straightforward ways of doing this programmatically, since you will already have a server/app running.

Having said that, employing it in any Java web application is, obviously, independent of the UI technology you might use (Vaadin included) and IMHO, it's better to reason about it separately.

For the sake of completeness, I will go through all the steps involved in adding Quartz to a Maven-managed, Java web application below.

**Adding Quartz as a Maven Dependency**

Adding one dependency in your *pom.xml* should suffice:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
  <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Initializing a Quartz Scheduler in a Servlet Container**

A default Quartz scheduler is automatically created and initialized upon Servlet Context initialization (as illustrated at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler.html) by declaring a servlet context listener and several context parameters to the *web.xml* descriptor:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
  <param-value>/quartz.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>quartz:start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>
    org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

You should also configure the scheduler by providing a basic *quartz.properties* file:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = LenartScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = LenartScheduler.ID
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

At this point, after the application has been deployed/started, a Quartz scheduler instance can be obtained from a "standard" scheduler factory available to you under a default key in the web application's ServletContext object:

```
StdSchedulerFactory schedFact = (StdSchedulerFactory)
  ctx.getAttribute("org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.KEY");
try {
    Scheduler scheduler = schedFact.getScheduler("LenartScheduler");
    // schedule Jobs here...
} catch (SchedulerException e) {
    // properly handle the exception...
}
```

Note that we've used the scheduler name (*LenartScheduler*) specified in the *quartz.properties* file above. As well, note that at this point, nothing is scheduled yet – all we have is a scheduler ready to be used.

**Creating the Job Class**

Easily done by implementing *org.quartz.Job*:

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class MainJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext)
      throws JobExecutionException {

        // Simulate job execution for 5 seconds...
        try {
            System.out.println("Executing job in background...");
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 5 /* secs */);
            System.out.println("Done executing job.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Scheduling the Job**

Given the available Scheduler, we need to define:

1. the so-called "details" of a Job

**AND**

2. a trigger for those details

and use them both to finally schedule the job:

```
private void scheduleMainJob(Scheduler scheduler) throws SchedulerException {
    requireNonNull(scheduler);

    JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(MainJob.class).storeDurably()
                                               .withIdentity("MAIN_JOB")
                                               .withDescription("Main Job to Perform")
                                               .build();
    Trigger trigger = newTrigger().forJob(jobDetail)
                                  .withIdentity("MAIN_JOB_TRIGG")
                                  .withDescription("Trigger for Main Job")
                 .withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(15).repeatForever())
                 .startNow().build();

    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
}
```

Note the simple way of specifying when to trigger the job (no *cron* expression involved for your simple case, at least not yet). For the sake of the example, I am triggering the job every 15 seconds and let it run for 5 -- if you want to trigger it every 24 hours (i.e. one a day) you can use *simpleSchedule().withIntervalInHours(24).repeatForever()*.

**Automatically Scheduling the Job**

Now, the astute will notice that we still haven’t called the scheduling functionality just yet. We could either do it ***"manually"***, by defining some sort of an admin servlet/UI and upon user interaction to call the scheduling method defined above or, if we are OK with using the predefined/hardcoded values, ***automatically***, upon servlet context start up, like we did it with the scheduler.

Let's say we want to automatically schedule the main job, upon servlet context start up. We again have at least 2 options:

1. *implement a ServletContextListener* that does/calls the scheduling routine above and make sure it is called after the QuartzInitializerListener we've declared in order to have the scheduler created

**OR**

2. *extend the QuartzInitializerListener* class to schedule our main job just after the scheduler gets created; this way, we don’t have to worry about the order in which the context listeners get called:

   ```
   public class LenartQuartzListener extends QuartzInitializerListener {

       @Override
       public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent evt) {
           super.contextInitialized(evt);
           // At this point, the default functionality
           // has been executed hence the scheduler has been created!
           ServletContext ctx = evt.getServletContext();
           StdSchedulerFactory factory = (StdSchedulerFactory)
             ctx.getAttribute("org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.KEY");
           try {
               scheduleMainJob(factory.getScheduler("LenartScheduler"));
           } catch (SchedulerException e) {
               // properly handle the exception...
           }
       }
   }
   ```

However, if we're using the (better, IMHO) second option, we do need to specified in the *web.xml* file our new Quartz listener, instead if the old one:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>com.lenard.web.LenartQuartzListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

At this point, never mind the UI technology used (Vaadin, etc.), a Quartz scheduler is automatically initialized and a job scheduled upon (web) application start up.

**If using Vaadin**

These days, one can initialize a Vaadin-based web application without using a web.xml descriptor. If that's your case, note that you now need to add the web.xml file that specifies the Quartz initialization we've been talking about. But this does not clash with any Vaadin-specific stuff…

I've created a small Vaadin-based project at https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/tree/master/so-42899401-quartz-maven-tomcat to illustrate how one can manually schedule / unschedule Quartz jobs using a Vaadin UI. Feel free to study it and ask ahead!

Comment: It  worked :D Tnx a lot for help :D You are the best : D I think whit this  tutorial I don't need any question is  noob proof. :D

Comment: Do you have any idea if i need anything to change if i want to import project  on AWS elastic beanstalk. It all ready worked on my Local server but when i upload on AWS i get MaxClientsThreads error.

Comment: I've never used AWS Elastic Beanstalk. But I guess you hit a limitation (maybe the plan you're using? is it a free one?). I guess you could try to reconfigure your scheduler to use less threads, i.e. use `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1` in the quartz.properties file above instead of 3... Let us know how that's going...

Comment: I solve problem :D I need to change servlet name. Now my project works :D

Answer (score 2):

Created a dummy boilerplate project for this. 
Have a look https://github.com/dhruvpsaru/quartz-test

In place of xml I am using annotations that I think is better way

pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>web-app</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>app Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
      <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
      <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Create a servlet as

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;


    @WebServlet(
            name = "AnnotatedServlet",
            description = "A sample annotated servlet",
            urlPatterns = {"/test"}
    )
    public class AppServlet extends HttpServlet {

        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

            logger.info("------------------------in servlet-------------------");

            PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
            writer.println("<html>Hello, I am a Java servlet!</html>");
            writer.flush();
        }
    }
```

Create a job class as

```
package quartz;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class SimpleJob implements Job {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.info("This is my first quartz job!!");
    }
}
```

and create a listener as

```
import org.quartz.*;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

@WebListener
public class QuartzScheduler implements ServletContextListener {

    private Scheduler scheduler = null;
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        logger.info("Context Initialized");

        try {
            // Setup the Job class and the Job group
            JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SimpleJob.class).withIdentity(
                    "CronQuartzJob", "Group").build();

            // Create a Trigger that fires every 5 minutes.
            Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("TriggerName", "Group")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
                    .build();

            // Setup the Job and Trigger with Scheduler & schedule jobs
            scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        logger.info("Context Destroyed");
        try
        {
            scheduler.shutdown();
        }
        catch (SchedulerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and now go and do `mvn clean package` and deploy `target/app.war`

Comment: @Lenart Poljanšek Have a look at link above. I tried it in tomcat 9.